# overflow:hidden hiding borders but not the element that overflows

Tags: css, overflow, hidden

I'm working on a header with a transition. But something is not working.

I made the ul 120px and li 60px. 
And I gave the li:hover a translateY(-60px). So that it pops up when you hover over the li.

I want to hide the content that is overflowing until you hover over it. But it doesn't seem to work. It does hover hide the border of the li that is overflowing.

Does anybody know why?

thank you in advance!

```
<header>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a id="p1" href="#">Vibe</a>

            <a id="p2" href="#">Vibe</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a id="p1" href="#">Creations</a>

            <a id="p2" href="#">Creations</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a id="p1" href="#">Vision</a>

            <a id="p2" href="#">Vision</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a id="p1" href="#">Just tell us</a>

            <a id="p2" href="#">Just tell us</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</header>
```

And this is the css

```
header {
height: 60px;
width: 100%;
background-color: #34495e;
}

header ul  {
    margin-right: 20px;
    float: right;
    height: 60px;   
    overflow: hidden;
}

header ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 120px;
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-right: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-left: 1px solid #2c3e50;
}

header ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 60px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: "lato", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #e74c3c;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);
}

#p2 {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    color: #c0392b;
    line-height: 60px;
}

header ul li:hover {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-60px);   
}
```

Comment: Please create a JSFiddle.By the way...IDs (such as #p1) **can only be used once per page.** You should change the IDs to classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution that may work for you:

**[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9s8Gc/)**

First id's should be reserved for single uses. Your #p1 & #p2 would be better written as classes. To solve your problem you only need `overflow:hidden;` on the highest level container, in this case the header. Also since you've given `#p2` absolute position, you also need to give the header `position:relative;`.

CSS:

```
header {
  // existing styles

  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: this was perfect. thank you. I thought that I had to give ul a position:relate because it was the parent. but it also works on the highest level container. That's awesome.

Comment: When you give an element position absolute, it will position based on the closest container with `position: relative;`.

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
position: relative;
```

To your ul class

Here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2jabu/

Comment: thanks! that totally worked ;). But can I ask you why I had to add position relative to the ul class. And not to li class. Because I used position:absolute on .p2 which is in the li?