# How can I show border bottom while keeping overflow-x: hidden?

Tags: html, css, border, overflow

How can I show a border bottom on an li inside a ul element while keeping horizontal overflow hidden. Below an example of what I have now (and do not want):

[image]

This is my current code (ul is dynamically generated by Ruby)

```
<div class="breadcrumbs">
    <div class="row breadcrumbs--row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
          <ul class="list--inline">
            <% @breadcrumbs.each_with_index do |(title, url), i| %>
              <!--<%= '»' if i > 0 %>-->
              <li> <%= '>' if i > 0 %> <a class="breadcrumbs--title" href="<%= url %>" title="<%= title %>"><%= title %></a></li>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And my CSS:

```
.breadcrumbs--row {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #e2e2e2;
  margin-left: -20px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  width: calc(100% + 40px);
}
.breadcrumbs ul {
  text-align: right;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: visible;
  white-space: nowrap;
  direction: rtl;
  position: relative;
}
.breadcrumbs ul:first-child:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, white 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 10%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, white 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 10%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, white 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 10%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#00ffffff',GradientType=1 );
}
.breadcrumbs ul li {
  display: inline;
}
.breadcrumbs ul li a {
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-bottom: 16px;
}
.breadcrumbs ul li:last-child a {
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #f77f00;
}
```

This is what I am trying to achieve, but then with a border bottom on the last li. (I need to hide the overflow on the left, so I have an overflow-x: hidden on the ul element):

[image]

What I tried:

- ul { overflow-y: visible; } (also tried that on parent element and keep overflow: visible on ul).
- Search Google (but that's difficult. I mean try to search for this issue for example).
- Look at CodePen examples
- Searched on StackOverflow for an answer, found some but they were either too specific or not working ([can someone tell me why my overflow-x is effecting my menu border?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24977559/can-someone-tell-me-why-my-overflow-x-is-effecting-my-menu-border), [overflow:hidden hiding borders but not the element that overflows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21503383/overflowhidden-hiding-borders-but-not-the-element-that-overflows))

Can someone also explain me why it is not working what I tried?

EDIT: See my CodePen example. Please copy the code instead of directly changing it: https://codepen.io/johnnybossboy/pen/PepwMX

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? In this case, show the generated HTML, not the Ruby code.

Comment: @MrLister I added my CodePen example

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you're looking for: [Link to project](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zjZBrJ)

Edit: I've changed a few things and on codepen it seems to be working.

```
/* Please scroll through code, as I have added useful comments. */
body {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.card {
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

a {
  color: black;
}

.breadcrumbs--row {
  border-bottom: 4px solid #e2e2e2;
  margin-left: -20px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  width: calc(100% + 40px);
  height: 50px;
}
.breadcrumbs ul {
  text-align: right;
  overflow-x: hidden; /* when this is visible, the border is shown, however the text overflows the container which is  undesired behaviour */
  /* ------changed this------- */
  overflow-y: hidden; /* Tried this, did not work as you can see */
  white-space: nowrap;
  direction: rtl;
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
}
.breadcrumbs ul:first-child:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, white 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 10%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, white 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 10%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, white 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 10%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#00ffffff',GradientType=1 );
}
.breadcrumbs ul li {
  display: inline;
}
.breadcrumbs ul li a {
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-bottom: 16px;
  height: 100%;
}
.test_box{
  border-bottom: 4px solid #f77f00;
  padding-bottom: 28px;
}

.breadcrumbs ul li:last-child a {
  /* -------changed this------ */
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
 /* THIS IS GONE. I want to have a border on the gray line below, while keeping the overflow on the left the same. Nevermind the gray square next to the horizontal gradient. It's irrelevant for my issue and does not happen on my site. */
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but not entirely. I want the border bottom to be on the same horizontal level as the border of the row.

Comment: It can also be a different solution, as long as there is an orange stripe at the same horizontal level of the row.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a way forward for you:

https://codepen.io/Cordazar/pen/QWZrgKb

The changes I made are:

```
.breadcrumbs ul {
  ...
  overflow-x: clip;
}
```

and

```
.breadcrumbs ul li:last-child a {
  ...
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

to firstly show the border and secondly place it correctly.